# Rails index.html.erb delete item - not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to delete an item from index.html.erb with following code:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', method: :delete, id: product.id, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

however all it does is try to show the index again.  How can I be more specific, I.e. - if this is a product from a category, how to I reference the path to this object in the database to delete it?

Comment: where did you specify path for delete

Comment: Thank you for your response...I did not as it show up in rake routes - I suppose I will have to do that?

Comment: didnt get your response i mean your link to should contain routes for delete product

Answer (score 0):

Define your action for delete and implement deleting a product in there.